# Pandas can't find a value in dataframe using values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1

| Index | geoid10 | precinct_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 360050020002003 | 43 |
| 2 | 360610005001008 | 1 |
| 3 | 360610008006013 | 5 |
| 4 | 360610151003000 | 20 |
| 5 | 360610241002002 | 33 |
| 6 | 360050255001000 | 52 |
| 7 | 360470002001014 | 72 |

df2

| Index | geoid10 | precinct_2020 | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 360610005001008 | 750 | 0 |
| 1 | 360610008006013 | 750 | 0 |
| 2 | 360610241002002 | 750 | 0 |
| 3 | 360050255001000 | 750 | 1990 |
| 4 | 360470002001014 | 750 | 333 |

As you can see, the 'geoid10' columns in df1 and df2 have matching values. However, when I try to search for each value of df1's geoid10 column inside df2's geoid10 column, my code returns "false". I have made sure that both 'geoid10' columns are ints.  Why is this happening?

Here is the sample for loop:

```
for gid in df1['geoid10']: 
  if gid in df2['geoid10']: 
    print("true")
  else: 
    print("false")
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas built-in function `isin`:

```
print(df1['geoid10'].isin(df2["geoid10"]))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list of the second dataframe in order to check if the interated gid is in the second dataframe.

```
for gid in df1["geoid10"]:
    if gid in list(df2["geoid10"]):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: I figured it was something so simple. If I did not create the list, what was my code searching?

Comment: @quokka Actually I have no idea, what you were searching for exactly .

Comment: df2 has a column with data that I need to populate into df1 and I needed to search df2 via the 'geoid10' index, but df2 would have been too large for me to just merge/concatenate the columns. thank you for your help!